# Is there any alternative of applying many .replace in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here I have more than 30 words that wish to replace, how can I improve the efficiency and no need to write more than 30 `replace`?

```js
"sample string".split(" ").map((x) => {
      return x
        .replace(/\bman\b/g, "manchester")
        .replace("/\butd\b/g", "united")...(still have 30 words to go)
    })
```

Comment: You can the pairs in an array and handle them using a loop.

Comment: if `man` appears, it must be Manchester because the source's domain is country instead of a paragraph. @mplungjan

Comment: *" the source's domain is country"*: what does that mean?

Comment: Please click [edit] then `[<>]` and add a sample input and expected output

Comment: the "man" must be transformed to "manchester", won't have other cases. @trincot

Comment: It would be good if you would add the other 30 cases literally in your question, and include more realistic input (not "sample string"). That way we can better determine which solution suits best your needs: give the most challenging inputs you can think of.

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://github.com/KooiInc/StringInterpolator)

Answer (score 4):

If you are only replacing *words*, i.e. using the `\b` boundary before and after the regex and no non-alphanumeric character to match, then use a look-up object, whose keys are the words you want to replace. One generic regex could even suffice:

```js
const translations = {
    "man": "manchester",
    "utd": "united",
};

const str = "this evening man utd will play again"; 
const result = str.replace(/\w+/g, word => translations[word] ?? word);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: No we don't. You're making random assumptions about a use case that might be something completely different.

Comment: @Behemoth I did not make assumptions. We got more information and the use case was confirmed not to exist

Answer (score 1):

You could do that dynamically with a lookup matrix that stores all your replacements.

```js
const replacements = [
  [/\bman\b/, "manchester"],
  [/\butd\b/, "united"]
];

const inputString = "sample string man man utd";

const result = inputString
  .split(" ")
  .map(word => replacements.find(r => r[0].test(word))?.[1] || word)
  .join(" ");

console.log(result);
```